# How to group datebase records into 15-minute time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have a table `user_access` with the following columns in MySQL database:

```
id      int
user    int
access_time    datetime
```

I am trying to run a query that gives me the number of times a `user` accesses the system (`access_time`) in 15-minute intervals within a given a given set of timestamps.

My current query is:

```
select user, count(user) as users from user_access
where (access_time between '2013-05-28 02:00:00' and '2013-05-28 10:00:00')
group by user
```

The results I'm trying to achieve would look like:

```
Time                User       No of Times
--------------------------------------------------
8:00am - 8:15am     user1          20
8:00am - 8:15am     user2          5
8:15am - 8:30am     user1          15
8:15am - 8:30am     user2          23
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if users have no accesses during the specified time periods?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nice one. I never thought of that. Zero when there are no records for a user.

Comment: Are the "results" you posted the *expected* results, or what the *current* results are?

Comment: @GigaWatt The results are the expected result format. I have not developed the query completely yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have a subtle error in your `WHERE` clause. You need:

```
where access_time >= '2013-05-28 02:00:00' 
  and access_time < '2013-05-28 10:00:00'
```

because your quarter-hour ranges run from a particular time until the moment *before* another particular time. You need  `<`, not `<=`, for the end of your time range.

Then, you need an expression that can take an arbitrary `DATETIME` expression and convert it to the `DATETIME` of the beginning of the quarter-hour in which it occurs.

This will do that.

```
DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') +
            INTERVAL (MINUTE(datestamp) -
                      MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 15) MINUTE
```

It turns, for example `'2014-05-07 14:53:22'`, into `'2014-05-07 14:45:00'`.

You can define it as a stored function like this if you like:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `TRUNC_15_MINUTES`$$
CREATE  FUNCTION `TRUNC_15_MINUTES`(datestamp DATETIME) 
                 RETURNS DATETIME
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') +
                INTERVAL (MINUTE(datestamp) -
                          MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 15) MINUTE$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can then write your query like this:

```
 select TRUNC_15_MINUTES(access_time) AS period_starting,
        user, count(user) as users 
   from user_access
 where access_time >= '2013-05-28 02:00:00' 
   and access_time <  '2013-05-28 10:00:00'
 group by TRUNC_15_MINUTES(access_time), user
 order by TRUNC_15_MINUTES(access_time), user
```

This is written up here. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: Nice response. I am still testing. How can I default `users` to `0` if  no result was returned for a particular 15 minute interval?

Comment: The inclusion of zero rows should be the topic of another question (unless @GordonLinoff knows some really slick trick).

Comment: I am currently testing the query, I will get back to you once I am done. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Any Idea on how I can include rows that have value for an interval and default `users` from the query as `0`

Comment: Like I said, this is a different question. But here's a pointer to some ideas.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to create is a formula that will turn each access_time into its nearest quarter-hour.

Something like:

```
CONCAT(Hour(access_time),":",floor(Minute(access_time)/15))*15)
```

Then you can put that formula both in your select statement and your group by statement.  You can modify this pseudocode statement to change your formatting, add the end time of each quarter hour, etc.

Comment: This is MySQL. You need `CONCAT()`, not `&`.

Comment: sorry.  pseudocode. Added Concat(). Point was to dynamically convert individual instants into quarter-hours

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it by using datediff and round.

Take an arbitrary date and use TIMESTAMPDIFF to get a decimal.  round that date to 15 minutes and then group by it.

so something like

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,randDate,access_time) DIV 15 as time, user, count(id) as users from user_access
    where (access_time > '2013-05-28 02:00:00' AND access_time < '2013-05-28 10:00:00')
    GROUP BY user, time
```

then all you have to do is go backwards to make it look pretty.  Do a date add to the randDate using time to get back to the 15 min interval.

This is pretty rough but it should give you enough to get on the right track.