# How to Aggregate 15 minute Time series into 1 hour intervals in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

In my PostgreSQL database I have a very large (over 40 mil) row table that represents traffic counts for various locations by 15 minute interval timestamps (contained in the "starttime" column).  I want to bin these intervals into hourly intervals to reduce the number of rows.

The format is "timestamp without time zone" so that each record looks like this:

`2020-04-26 01:00:00`
`2020-04-26 01:15:00`
`2020-04-26 01:30:00`
`2020-04-26 01:45:00`
etc...

What I want to do is take all these 15-min records and "roll them up" into 1 hour intervals so that `01:00:00`- `01:45:00` would equal `01:00:00` (1AM)

[My question is similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916602/how-to-group-datebase-records-into-15-minute-time-intervals) but the answer is with regard to MySQL and I am not sure if this syntax is appropriate for a Postgres application.

Is there a way I can handle this with an SQL script within Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `date_trunc()`.  For instance to get the count by hour:

```
select date_trunc('hour', ts), count(*)
from t
group by date_trunc('hour', ts)
```

Comment: perfect!  Thanks a lot!